# What does adding '().days' in a variable work?

Tags: python, function, datetime

So I am doing a course on Python and was on a chapter quiz. The first time I answered the question, I was wrong, then I saw the actual answer. The two unknown's were `(bday-today).days`. Additionally, I also want to know how `"Birthday in %d days" % (diff+365)` works.

Here's the code:

```py
from datetime import *

def main():
    today=date.today()
    bday=date(today.year,12,13)
    diff=(bday-today).days
    if diff>0:
     print("Birthday in %d days" % diff)
    else:
     print("Birthday in %d days" % (diff+365))

main()
```

Comment: `bday-today` creates a `timedelta` object, which has an attribute `days`

Comment: @tobias_k Thank you for explaining that, but I have seen people put `.days` **inside** the parentheses. How does it change the output (or does it)?

Comment: Inside the parens it would be equivalent to `bday - (today.days)` which does not make sense. You want the days of the result of the subtraction, hence the parens, since usually `.` has priority over `-`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for `(bday-today).days`, it often surprises people when they see a method called on an expression like `(a + b)`.  It doesn't make sense that `(a + b).method()` could ever work.

However, you're not calling `.method()` on the parentheses; you're calling it on the result of `a + b`, which should be an object that supports calling `.method()`.

Consider this code:

```
a = "Hello, "
b = "World!"
```

What if you want to find the length of the combined string?  Well, you could do this:

```
c = a + b
print( len(c) )
```

But you can save a step with:

```
print( len(a + b) )
```

This probably doesn't surprise you too much, but let's change the question a little bit:

What if you wanted the upper-case equivalent of the combined string?  Well, you could write:

```
c = a + b
print( c.upper() )
```

Or, you could save a step and do:

```
print( (a + b).upper() )
```

Because you may have never seen a parenthesized expression having a method called on it, this may look bizarre to you.  But all that's happening is that (a + b) is creating a new object (which is a `str` object), which then gets its `.upper()` method called.

You may (or may not) have even seen code like this:

```
some_function().some_action()
```

That looks wrong, but is it?  It looks like we're calling a method of a function!

But we're not.  What's really going on is that `some_function()` is returning an object, and this object has a `.some_action()` method that can be called.  Basically, the above code is really no different than:

```
var = some_function()
var.some_action()
```

(except that the returned value of `some_function()` is not stored off in a variable).

And this isn't a Python quirk; this behavior is found in C++, Java, and pretty much every other Obejct-Oriented language there is.

(Don't feel bad if you didn't know about this.  I worked with a professional C++ programmer (with over a decade of experience) who didn't know that that was possible in C++.  When I explained to him that it worked, he thought it was best to "play it safe" and not use that construct -- because, you know, "the compiler might not support it!"  However, this *must* be supported by Object-Oriented languages -- otherwise, a fundamental property of OO is broken -- namely, that objects (even returned objects) can have their methods called.)

---

As for `"Birthday in %d days" % (diff+365)`, it's an old way of formatting text that's been replaced by `f-strings` and the `str.format()`.  Basically, these lines are equivalent:

```
"Birthday in %d days" % (diff+365)   # Usually found in Python 2.X
"Birthday in {} days".format(diff+365)  # Usually found in Python 3.X
f"Birthday in {diff+365} days"   # Usually found in Python 3.X
```

If you're used to programming in Python 3.X, it's no surprise that it looks unfamiliar to you.  I recommend reading up a little on it (so you can recognize if for what it is), but using the other format methods when writing your own code.

Answer (score 1):

The line `diff = (bday - today).days` gets the difference between `bday` and `today`, which is an instance of `datetime.timedelta`, and then gets the `days` attribute from that `timedelta`, and thus the number of days until (or since) the birthday. The parens are necessary, since without, `bday - today.days` would be evaluated as `bday - (today.days)`, which would not make sense.

Similarly, `"Birthday in %d days" % (diff+365)` is basically just the same as two lines above, but adding `356` to the number of days before putting them where the `%d` is in the string. Again, the parens are necessary since `%` is technically still a "multiplication/division" type operation, even though it is used differently here, and thus stronger binding than addition, i.e. without it would be evaluated as `("Birthday in %d days" % diff) + 365`, which, again, would not make sense.